# Set of links to be disabled when clicking any one link

Tags: php, javascript, html, hyperlink

I have 5(say) links inside a `<div>` tag in a php page. When a visitor clicks on any one of the links all the 5 has to be disabled. How to make this possible? I have some idea to make the link disabled on which the user clicks

```
<a href="someaction" onClick='this.disabled=true;'>LINK 1</a>
<a href="someaction" onClick='this.disabled=true;'>LINK 2</a>
<a href="someaction" onClick='this.disabled=true;'>LINK 3</a>
<a href="someaction" onClick='this.disabled=true;'>LINK 4</a>
<a href="someaction" onClick='this.disabled=true;'>LINK 5</a>
```

So if I click LINK 1 only the LINK 1 will be disabled. I need to disable all the 5 links (only these five not the other links in the page).

Suggest me simple and best way :)

Comment: And what when a user reloads the page? Should the links be again clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Sure if it is the best way, but certainly, it'll do the job.

```
function removeLink(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'LINK 1<br />LINK 2<br />LINK 3<br />LINK 4<br />LINK 5<br />';

}

<span id="removeLinkId">
    <a href="someaction" onClick="removeLinks('removeLinkId');">LINK 1</a>
    <a href="someaction" onClick="removeLinks('removeLinkId');">LINK 2</a>
    <a href="someaction" onClick="removeLinks('removeLinkId');">LINK 3</a>
    <a href="someaction" onClick="removeLinks('removeLinkId');">LINK 4</a>
    <a href="someaction" onClick="removeLinks('removeLinkId');">LINK 5</a>
</span>
```

Comment: I don't like this approach very much... The one from @antyrat is much better and simpler.

Comment: Me neither. But as of now, it is working for all 5 links. This case is somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` tag doesn't support `disabled` attribute, only `input`, `textarea`, `button` does.

If you want to make link non clickable you can null `href` attribute:

```
<a href="someaction" onClick='this.href="";'>LINK 5</a>
```

Or you can emulate `disabled` attribute:

```
<a href="someaction" onClick='if(this.disabled){ return false; } else { this.disabled = true; }'>LINK 5</a>
```

It will prevent future clicks.

Comment: Oops!! okay is there any possibility to disable all the links when any link is clicked?

Comment: okay!! changed the idea let me use 5 buttons over there. is there any possibility to disable all the 5 buttons when any pne clicked?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="www.google.se" id="foo">LINK 1</a>
```

Javascript:

```
//Get the element you need.
var a = getElementById("foo");

//Remember to use the REFERENCE, not actually CALLING the callback.
a.onclick = callback;

function callback() {
    //a.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    a.removeAttribute("href");
    return false; //Stop the event (don't navigate
}
```

Javascript JQUERY:

```
//Get the element and bind it in one "line".
var a = $("a#foo);
a.bind(
    "click",
    function() {

        a.hide();
        a.removeAttr("href");

        //Stop the event from bubbling
        return false; 
    });
```